# Calculate subtotal over column with aggregate functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
       A              B         C            D         E         F
1                   2300       #NA           0
2
3   Product A       500        #NA         500
4   Product B       400        100         500
5   Product C       300        #NA         300
6   Product D       200        800        1.000
7   Product E       900        900        1.800
8
```

In the table above I have list of products in `Column A`. 
In `Column B` and `Column C` I have corresponding values to those products. 
In `Column D` I want to `Sum` the values from `Column B` and `Column C`. 
As you can see `Column C` contains `=NA` values. In order to ignore them I went with `=AGGREGATE(9,6,B3:C3)` in `Column D`.

Alls this works exactly the way I want it.

---

However, now in `Cell D1` I want to `sum up` the values in `Column D` but instead of using `SUM` I want to go with `=SUBTOTAL(9,D3:D7)` because I am going to apply a filter to the list later on.

The `subtotal` formula gives me `0` as a result. When I type the values in `Column D` manually in `Column E` and put the `subtotal` formula over `Column E` it works. Therefore, I assume this issue is somehow caused by the `AGGREGATE` function in `Column D`.

How do I have to modify the formula in `Cell D1` or the formulas in `Column D` to get the correct subtotal?

Comment: instead of aggregate you could use a array formula, like so: `{=sum(iferror(b3:c3,0))}`. The brackets `{}`indicate an array formula, enter with `ctrl`+`shift`+`enter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `7` in the second criterion instead of `6` to ignore errors and hidden rows:

```
=AGGREGATE(9,7,B3:B7)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't use AGGREGATE function in a filter list, and try to use SUMIF instead

In `B1`, copied right to `C1`

```
=SUMIF(B3:B8,">0")
```

In `D1`:

```
=SUBTOTAL(9,D3:D8)
```

In `D3`, copied down :

```
=SUMIF(B3:C3,">0")
```

Remark : I added a "Product A" and value in row 8 for Filter testing

[image]